How to deploy GitLab runner artifacts to machine
I have gitlab-runner as docker container. And at the last stage I want to copy build/ folder to nginx directory, that is on the same server.
Simple: copy files from docker-image to the local server, where docker is running.
My pipeline:
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - test2

Unit testing:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test-all
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

Building and deploy:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
    expire_in: 1 week

Auto tests:
  stage: test2
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb -y
    - cd e2e
    - npm ci
    - npx cypress run
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - e2e/cypress/screenshots
      - cypress/screenshots
    expire_in: 1 week
  allow_failure: true

I tried find files in the system, but has only node_modules and other project files...
